# Python Hadoop streaming, secondary sorting issues

Tags: algorithm, sorting, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

Hadoop newbie here. I have some user-events logs like this, with **userid** and **timestamp** both randomly ordered:

```
userid  timestamp           serviceId
 aaa    2012-01-01 13:12:23 4
 aaa    2012-01-01 12:11:52 3
 ccc    2012-01-03 08:13:07 3
 bbb    2012-01-02 02:34:12 8
 aaa    2012-01-02 01:09:47 4
 ccc    2012-01-02 12:15:39 4
```

I want to get intermediate result sorted by **userid** and then **timestamp**, like below:

```
 aaa    2012-01-01 12:11:52 3
 aaa    2012-01-01 13:12:23 4
 aaa    2012-01-02 01:09:47 4
 bbb    2012-01-02 02:34:12 8
 ccc    2012-01-02 12:15:39 4
 ccc    2012-01-03 08:13:07 3
```

so it could be easily parsed by my Reducer.

The final goal is to calculate how a user spent his time on different services(serviceIds). Is this achievable using Python Hadoop streaming? If not then what's a better approach you would suggest? Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mapper you could emit `userid` as key and `timestamp` and `serviceId` as values sorted by `timestamp` (to perform the sorting operation, I'm assuming all the rows per user can fit in main memory).

Then the MR framework will take care of sending all the different rows per user to a single reducer, and you could easily perform your analysis there.

If there are too many rows per user (say millions), you could emit `userId-serviceId` as key, and after the reduce phase you'd have a one line file per `user-service` with the time spent on that service. If you want, you can then join all those files using [getmerge](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#getmerge)

Comment: Great, thanks! So using either 'userId' or 'userId-serviceId' as key, basically I need to sort the values by 'timestamp' in my Reducers. What if I want the output from Mapper already sorted by timestamp before reaching Reducer? I know I can specify a custom Partitioner in Java (using 'userId-timestamp' as composite key but partitioning on 'userId'), but is this possible in Python streaming as well? Thx!

Comment: Yes, you could set `userid-timestamp` as key, and then partition by `userid` using the `-partitioner` clause of hadoop streaming. Check out [this example](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html#Hadoop+Partitioner+Class) in the official documentation.